# Android Studio Return Type No Match

Tags: android, java-native-interface

**Question:**

Does anyone know why CallCharMethod does not work? It is logging CallCharMethodV which is weird, because as you can see below, I am not using CallCharMethodV. Some help would be appreciated it.

**Error:**

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: the return type of CallCharMethodV does not match java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()

**Code:**

```
globalEnv->CallVoidMethod(jobj, globalEnv->GetMethodID(env->GetObjectClass(jobj), "sendToastMessage", "(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V"),
            env->CallCharMethod(jview, env->GetMethodID(env->FindClass("android/widget/TextView"), "getText", "()Ljava/lang/CharSequence;")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.lang.CharSequence` is an interface, so whatever is returned from that method will be an object, not a `char`. Use `CallObjectMethod` instead.

The reason that it is complaining about CallCharMethod**V** is because CallCharMethod forwards its variable argument list to that method.